# calling a C++ function and change its parameter(a linked list)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, linked-list

I am a beginner in C++,I have a linked list defined in main I give it to a function as a parameter,inside that function the list is changed but when the program comes out from the function the linked list is unchanged what should I do?
it's like this

```
mnlist nodes;
nodes.first = NULL:
typelist typel;
typel.first = NULL;
nodes = list-scheduling(nodes,typel);//this is my function
```

but typel doesn't change when program exits from list-scheduling

Comment: What's the signature of your function? (In other words, could you please show us your function?).

Comment: Pass by value/Pass by refernce

Answer (score 1):

(I don't know how a function with the name "list-scheduling" compiled...)

Anyways, use references. Instead of

```
void foo(LinkedList l);
```

declare it as

```
void foo(LinkedList &l);
```

Comment: Maybe his subtracting the result of `scheduling()` from an object called `list`... :-)

Comment: @MarkGarcia LOL, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should Read [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs213/2002fa/lectures/Lecture02/Lecture02.pdf)

Pass by value :

```
int n =10
function(int n)
{
n++;
cout<<n ;  //n==11
}
cout<<n ; //n=10. only local value changes
```

pass by refernce :

```
int n=10;
function(int &n)
{
n++;
cout<<n ; //n=11
}
cout<<n; //n=11. Passed address of n, so changes will reflect
```